# Окончить жизнь самоубийством

Tags: грамотная-речь

Недавно на одном сайте возник спор о том, как правильно употреблять фразу "окончить жизнь самоубийством". Вернее, о том, как нужно: "закончить жизнь самоубийством", "окончить..." или "закончить"? Автор употребил первый вариант, но на него накинулись, что это неправильно. Честно говоря, я бы тоже употребила первый. Что же в нем неправильного?
Есть еще вариант "покончить с жизнью" — тут, вроде, все понятно.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этой фразой.

Comment: Неправильность усмотрели, скорее всего, по аналогии с "окончить институт/закончить учебу". Закончить - завершить процесс, окончить - пройти курс обучения. Все источники, занимающиеся ликбезом, вколачивают в умы эту разницу. И видимо, вышибли воспоминания о другом значении слова "окончить".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании настоящего времени, как правило применяют формы *покончил с жизнью (с собой)*.  Самоубийство - это не средство, как во всех упоминавшихся в вопросе вариантах, а цель, соответственно творительный падеж слову вообще мало подходит. Самоубийство *совершают*. А то получится что-то вроде: *Жизнь свою он окончил на лоне природы, в идилическом пасторальном пейзаже повесившись.*

Comment: ЧАСТОТНОСТЬ употребления трех вариантов такова: "Для прокутившихся студентов существуют трогательные телеграммы к родителям с просьбой прислать деньги раньше срока и с угрозой в случае отказа покончить жизнь самоубийством". [Илья Ильф, Евгений Петров.(65) "В конце концов, жизнь и смерть стоят друг друга, так что часто предпочтительно покончить с жизнью самоубийством".(1) [И. И. Мечников. «Милый папаша, мне двадцать три года, а я еще ничего не сделал; убежденный, что из меня ничего не выйдет, я решился покончить с жизнью… » [Ф. М. Достоевский) (25).

Comment: @София, а *покончить с собой" имеет 313 вхождений.

Answer (score 2):

Жизнь самоубийством можно либо покончить , либо кончить. Окончить - устар. См. в словорях.
КОНЧИТЬ, -чу, -чишь; конченный; -чен, -а, -о; св.
***3.***
Завершить свою жизнь, деятельность чем-л., каким-л. образом. ***Я кончу тем, что уеду на край света. Он плохо кончит
(не оправдает возлагавшихся на него надежд, потеряет достоинство, опустится). К. жизнь, век, дни
(умереть).*** К. жизнь самоубийством
(убить себя).*********
ОКОНЧИТЬ, ***-чу, -чишь; св. что.***
1.
Довести до конца; кончить, закончить. ***О. работу досрочно. О. посевную. О. рассказ, пьесу. О. брифинг, конференцию. О. съёмки. О. чтение законопроекта. Заседание окончено, все свободны. На том и окончим. О. своё выступление на мажорной ноте. // чем.
Сделать что-л. в заключение, завершить чем-л. О. речь здравицей. О. письмо поздравлением и наилучшими пожеланиями.
2.
Пройти какой-л. курс обучения, завершить обучение где-л. О. школу, институт, курсы повышения квалификации, аспирантуру. О. с трудом восемь классов. О. блестяще, с золотой медалью, с похвальной грамотой. < Оканчивать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Окончание, -я; ср. Оканчивание, -я; ср.***
ПОКОНЧИТЬ, -чу, -чишь; св.
1. с чем.
***Довести до конца, завершить (какое-л. дело, занятие). П. с завтраком. [] безл. До утра с работой покончено. С уроками покончено, можно отдохнуть. // с кем-чем и (реже) что.***
Положить конец, предел чему-л., прекратить, оборвать что-л. П. с безработицей. П. с войной. П. с беспечностью. С этим надо п.
(такие вещи не должны повторяться). П. с жизнью; п. жизнь самоубийством***
(убить себя, насильственно прервать свою жизнь). П. (все) счёты, расчёты с кем-, чем-л.
(прекратить отношения, связи с кем-, чем-л.). Придётся п. со сценой. [] безл. С прежним отношением к учёбе покончено. С этим человеком покончено
(прекращены отношения, разорваны связи).
2. с кем и (нар.-разг.) кого.
Лишить жизни, убить кого-л. П. с предателем, с заключённым. П. волка. П. с собой
(совершить самоубийство). // с кем-чем.
Уничтожить, разбить (неприятельскую армию, флот и т.п.). П. с фашистами. [] безл. С эскадрой противника было покончено.

Окончить жизнь — чью. ***Устар***. ***Убить, лишить жизни кого либо.*** [Святослав:] Рази, губи меня, мне век к напастям дан, Окончи жизнь мою, бедами отягчённу ***(.… …   Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка)***.

Comment: Как объяснить: покончить (что) жизнь - неправильное управление, покончить жизнь самоубийством - правильный вариант?

Comment: >> Как объяснить: покончить (что) жизнь - неправильное управление, покончить жизнь самоубийством - правильный вариант?

Вероятно, "покончить жизнь самоубийством" произошло от "покончить с собой". Так говорят, и точка.

Answer (score 1):

1) Жизнь можно окончить или закончить, например:

Кампанелла приехал во Францию, где и закончил жизнь в доминиканском монастыре, занимаясь философией, астрономией, составлением гороскопов. Больной и полуслепой, Эстрин окончил жизнь в интернате для престарелых. Художник окончил жизнь в монастыре. Острожский окончил жизнь в феврале 1608 года в глубокой старости.

2) При наличии Т.п. возникают семантические варианты: как/каким образом и кем/чем, например:

Он так же, как и многие, рано окончил жизнь самоубийством (в текстах обычно встречается только этот вариант). В США начал работать мойщиком посуды, а закончил жизнь кинозвездой. Рутинер  закончил жизнь ректором, увенчанным регалиями полного генерала.

3) ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ
ОКОНЧИТЬ (чем) – сделать что-л. в заключение, завершить чем-л. О. речь здравицей.  ЗАКОНЧИТЬ  – довести до конца, завершить.

4) КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Приставка О имеет значение общего отношения к действию,  а приставка ЗА  обычно обозначает результат.  Поэтому «окончить» можно дополнительно распространить обстоятельством образа действия (как?), а «закончить»  чаще имеет при себе дополнение  с двойной связью: он закончил (кем?).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Также встречается  "покончить жизнь самоубийством". Но "покончить жизнь" - это грамматически неверно, так как у глагола сильное управление: покончить с кем/чем. Интересно дать оценку этом варианту.

Comment: >> Он так же, как и многие, рано окончил жизнь самоубийством (в текстах обычно встречается только этот вариант).

В НОРМАЛЬНЫХ текстах встречается только "покончить жизнь самоубийством". Кошмар какой...

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то слово "покончить" употребляется в словосочетании "покончить с собой".

Comment: Не только. Покончить жизнь самоубийством - тоже употребляется. И никак уж не "окончить".

Answer (score 0):

Наряду с "покончить с чем" словарь допускает в некоторых случаях "покончить что" (п. жизнь самоубийством, п. (все) счёты, расчёты с кем-, чем-л.)

В Нацкопрусе предобладает вариант "**покончить** жизнь самоубийство**.

> С войной **покончили** мы счеты,//Бери шинель, пошли домой.(Б. Окуджава)
>
> [ПОКОНЧИТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x), -чу, -чишь; св. 1. с чем. Довести до конца, завершить (какое-л. дело, занятие). П. с завтраком. □безл. До утра с работой покончено. С уроками покончено, можно отдохнуть. // с кем-чем и (реже) что. Положить конец, предел чему-л., прекратить, оборвать что-л. П. с безработицей. П. с войной. П. с беспечностью. С этим надо п. (такие вещи не должны повторяться). П. с жизнью; **п. жизнь самоубийством (убить себя, насильственно прервать свою жизнь). П. (все) счёты, расчёты с кем-, чем-л. (прекратить отношения, связи с кем-, чем-л.)**. Придётся п. со сценой. □безл. С прежним отношением к учёбе покончено. С этим человеком покончено (прекращены отношения, разорваны связи). 2. с кем и (нар.-разг.) кого. Лишить жизни, убить кого-л. П. с предателем, с заключённым. П. волка. П. с собой (совершить самоубийство). // с кем-чем. Уничтожить, разбить (неприятельскую армию, флот и т.п.). П. с фашистами. □безл. С эскадрой противника было покончено